# 500 error in Sitecore RebuildReportingDB.aspx

Tags: sitecore-client, reporting

We are getting the `500 error` in rebuild reporting database page

`/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx`

and our Sitecore version is `10.2`

What we need to check to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: First check log files on the server if you can find any details there

Comment: Same stacktrace error only there also.

Comment: Replace screenshot with full stacktrace from your logs. Full, including nested exceptions.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? If yes can you help in providing resolution steps since we are also facing the same issue in our 10.3 sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first is to check your Sitecore logs for the specific error details.

Then make sure that your CM and processing server have access to the secondary reporting database. If you have multiple processing servers then ensure that all active ones have access to the secondary database.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issues in `Sitecore 10.2 nonprod` environments.
Basic things to check to sort out this issue are,

1. Check any evident information on Sitecore logs.
2. In my case, I have updated wrong connection string in Processing server. So make sure all your `Sitecore roles/servers(PRC)` has valid connection string entry, basically look for Master and Core DB entries.
3. If Device detection is an out of scope in your application, suggestion is to disable device detection on `CM`, `CD` and `PRC`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-sitecore-device-detection.html